# Are there lint to detect CSS inline style which no need to used or blank?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, lint

I doubt that there are lint to check about css inline style which we type but no need to use.

For example,

in .js file

```
 line: {
    borderBottom: '1px #ddd solid',
    paddingBottom: '5px',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    border: '1px solid #ddd',
    padding: '10px',
    marginTop: '10px',
    marginBottom: '10px',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  container: {

  },
```

in file which call .js

```
      <div style={styles.line}>
```

From example, in the file that use style not need container or in the styles.line no need to use all of it(Put too much style beyond the actual use.).  Is there any lint to detect and warning, error or delete automatic those one that I refer?

Thanks.

Comment: An interesting concept. It would be interesting to see how the affected the performance of the page. Each item needs to be applied individually and thereby causing a page reflow for each instruction.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-inline-styles does the job

yes, u can add this to ur `.eslintrc.json`
as described in docs

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-no-inline-styles"
  ]
}
{
  "rules": {
    "no-inline-styles/no-inline-styles": 2
  } 
}
```

this is the result ☺️
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into CSS Modules. They enable you to add css to your React components on a per component basis.

For example

Component (HelloWorld.js)

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import styles from './HelloWorld.css'

class HelloWorld extends Component{
    render(){
       return(
           <h1 className={styles.title}>Hello World</h1>
       )
    }
}

export default HelloWorld
```

CSS (HelloWorld.css)

```
.title{
   font-size: 48px;
   color: #ff0000;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Because this is pure CSS, and not some javascript port of it, you are able to gain back all of the linting capabilities you are used to with any other CSS file.